# Interpreting little-$o$ notation

Tags: asymptotics

This is the integrand of a complex integral:

$$\frac{o(\zeta - z)}{\zeta - z}$$

The ensuing discussion says that this can be made as small as desired [by confining $\zeta$ close to $z$].

In general I thought little-$o$ notation implied that given two functions,

$f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x \rightarrow a$ if  $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$$

I would appreciate help in seeing how to apply this to the above integrand to see how it can be made as small as desired.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take your definition of little-O, taking $g(\zeta) = \zeta -z$, taking $f$ to be the little-o function of $g$ in the numerator, and $D$ to be the domain you have:

$$\lim_{\zeta \to z}\frac{f(\zeta)}{g(\zeta)} = 0$$ implies

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0: \forall \zeta \in D: 0<|\zeta - z| < \delta \implies |\frac{f(\zeta)}{g(\zeta)}|<\epsilon$$

$$\implies |\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}|<\epsilon$$

By the definition of limits.

So your however small ($\epsilon$) you want the magnitude of your quotient ($|\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}|$) to be, you can bound it below that just by finding the appropriate $\delta$.

So your integrand can be as small as you wish. If you're asking about the integral itself, look up the estimation lemma.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma